# Woocommerce category slug (permalink) redirect to old url

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, http-status-code-301, slug

in Woocommerce I changed one of my category slug from A to something else like B and then return it to the original one (A again) for just couple of minutes

now whatever I do (even removing that category and rebuild new one) doesnt fix it and it redirects to B

I cleared the cache, changed permalink settings completely then back again, installed Redirect plugin and tried to add this address for redirection, I even removed the category, build a new one with the same properties

the error is `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in chrome and people call it 301

many suggest disable plugins and rebuild `.htaccess` but I have like 40 plugins on my site, I think its too risky, can you please suggest me a better way?